# Forbid ASP.NET web service listing with 403

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services

I'm looking for a way to return a 403 when an ASP.NET web service is accessed without an operation selected. That is, when you access just the .asmx file, you get a 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is no operation selected, in the else part try doing something like below:

```
Context.Response.Status = "403 Forbidden"; 
Context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
Context.Response.End();
```

[More about Context object.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.response.aspx)

[Try this answer if you might want to check the action/operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3309235/1211329), if those doesn't match with any of your operations then change the status code.

Comment: I'm a little confused; I only have the methods that can be called, not a page load method or similar in which I can check the operation.

Comment: @Dan please check the updated answer, might help as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! You need a Web.config entry :

```
<webServices>
  <wsdlHelpGenerator href="403.aspx"/>
</webServices>
```